# test-kitchen: unable to use ENV variable in .kitchen.yml on Windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra, yaml, erb, test-kitchen

It appears I'm unable to use erb in the `.kitchen.yml` when using the `ENV` var on Windows platforms.

```
$ kitchen list
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: Error parsing C:/Users/anonymous/.kitchen.yml as YAML.
Please run `kitchen diagnose --no-instances --loader' to help debug your issue.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

**.kitchen.yml**

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  synced_folders:
    - [<%= ENV['PWD'] %>, '/tmp/foo']

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04

suites:
  - name: default
```

**ENV**

```
$ chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.4.17
chef-client version: 13.6.4
delivery version: master (73ebb72a6c42b3d2ff5370c476be800fee7e5427)
berks version: 6.3.1
kitchen version: 1.19.2
inspec version: 1.45.13
```

This works fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, using the same file and software versions.

I believe this is related to a similar issue reported on the cucumber/aruba project ~ https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues/291

I tried submitting a new issue to the test-kitchen project but they refer me to their [contributing guidelines](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) which just goes over a release process.  Since I'm unable to submit a new issue I've come to SO hoping for either some clarity or a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that after the Erb replacement, this would look like `- [C:\Users\anonymous, '/tmp/foo']`. The `:` in there is an important YAML syntax character. The simple solution would be `- ["<%= ENV['PWD'] %>", '/tmp/foo']` or `- [<%= ENV['PWD'].to_json %>, '/tmp/foo']` (JSON is a subset of YAML).